# Should I call base class' methods in Windows services?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services

When deriving from `ServiceBase`, should I call the methods of the base class, too?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    //
    // The stuff I do when the service starts.
    //

    base.OnStart(args); // Do I need to call this?
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you should.

In this specific case, the base implementation of the OnStart method doesn't do anything significant, but that is an implementation detail which could change at any time. As a general practice, you should always call the base method unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 5):

If you decompile the service base with ILSpy or similar, you will see, that OnStart, OnStop, etc. do nothing (at least in .NET 4.0/4.5).

But this behaviour could change some time, so there could be unwanted or unpredicted behaviour in future releases of .NET, if you do not call it.
I think it's a good practice to call those base.OnEvent()-Methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I ever called base.OnStart when I wrote services.

If you *do*, however, always make the base class call the *first* line of your method, *not* the last!

Comment: Everything I have ever read on overriding has stated that base reference is always called first.  I'd have to test, but I think the compiler may require it.

Comment: @KennyZ:  The compiler does not require it.  You can call it whenever you want or not at all.